# Where can I store my private bookmarks online?

Tags: webapp-rec, bookmarks

I want to store my bookmarks online, but I am not interested in sharing them with other people. I used to use [myhq.com](http://myhq.com), but the interface is too clunky.

These days, [bkmks.com](http://bkmks.com) fits almost all my needs:

- fast & simple (can add new links with a bookmarklet; no unneeded graphics)
- can organize links by drag and drop

However, I have a few complaints:

- I'd like to remove the search box. It grabs the focus and prevents me from searching the page text with the '/' key in Opera
- Deleting (multiple) links is difficult (I had to make a hack to delete more than one link at a time)
- I'd like to separate groups of links on different tabs/pages so they don't all have to be loaded

Can anyone recommend a better service for organizing your private bookmarks online?

Comment: And you just made me discover finally the "page text search" that I was missing in my Opera, thank you.

Answer (score 22):

**Update**: If you are a rare [Delicious](http://www.delicious.com/) user,  and unaware about the [AVOS Acquisition](http://www.avos.com/delicious-press-release/),
You should **transition** your delicious account as described in this [FAQ](http://www.delicious.com/help/transition).

---

[**Delicious**](http://delicious.com/help/getStarted) using the private option.

> [**Are my bookmarks public or private by default, and how do I make a bookmark public or private?**](http://delicious.com/help/faq#bookmarks)
>
> Bookmarks saved with your buttons are public by default, but imported bookmarks are private by default. If you see a grey block and a lock next to a bookmark, that means it is a private bookmark and only you can see it (there is also a Share link added before the Edit link). Note: if you're logged out, you won't be able to see your private bookmarks either.
>
> To change a private bookmark to public (so that everyone else can see it), click the Share link next to it. To change a public bookmark to private, edit it, check the do not share box, and save it. **While saving a new bookmark, you can also check the do not share box to make that bookmark private**.

---

1. You never need to delete bookmarks (its no weight), however, you can delete if you need to

   - Delicious has a concept of `bundles` of `tags` to group tags
   - And, lets not forget, search-able `tags` itself is a great feature
   - You retain the ability of marking a bookmark public or sharing it with other Delicious users privately very fast
   - Delicious is integrating with other on-line tools and keeps getting [new features](http://delicious.com/help/whatsnew)
   - You can also keep a backup (exported copy) of your bookmarks with all the tagging information

Comment: The delicious firefox plugin is also great, and gives easy access to your bookmarks. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3615

Comment: Did Delicious always have private bookmarks? I recall considering it a long time ago... I miss being able to visually arrange my bookmarks, but the tag search feature makes this less of a problem. Also Delicious imported my bookmarks from Bkmks.com very well!

Comment: @wonsungi, Delicious had private bookmarks as long as I can remember.

Answer (score 18):

[XMarks](http://www.xmarks.com/) (originally Foxmarks) is pretty good, and has a plugin for most browsers.

Comment: Xmarks is undoubtedly THE best tool for seamlessly syncing bookmarks if you are a Firefox user.

Comment: I doubt if there is support for IE.

Comment: Actually there is support for IE. Would a quick google kill you before you respond?

Answer (score 4):

You could use [Google Bookmarks](http://www.google.com/bookmarks/). I use it in combination with the [GMarks](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2888) Firefox extension, and it works great. I find it to be nice and simple if all you want is to store them online, and use them from more than one machine.

Comment: Gmarks is (for me ) often does not work properly.  Not sure if this is a problem with Gmarks or Google Bookmarks.

Answer (score 3):

If you're already using Opera, why not just use the built-in [Opera Link](http://www.opera.com/link/)?

> File > Synchronize Opera...

It basically keeps a copy of your bookmarks on their server and you can synch it across devices as long as you log in with your Opera credentials.

You can access the page and clean up the bookmarks as you please, and it keeps the entire thing private, which means you don't have to check on each link to say so.

If you ever needed to come back and use your bookmarks on another computer, or need to restore after a format, you can synch down from their servers.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Opera, note that you can access the bookmarks saved in Opera Link from a webpage too : http://my.opera.com > Opera > bookmarks

This page is for private view only, and is found at a link like http://my.opera.com/{account}/account/link/bookmarks/

Using it, you would be able to manage your bookmark easily (from Opera), and still have them available on a webpage (if I understood the need correctly)

Answer (score 0):

I use MyYahoo for my bookmarks.  It also doubles as an RSS reader.

Comment: Can you add why you use MyYahoo for your bookmarks? What makes that service a good fit for answering the question?

Answer (score 0):

I like the [sitebar](http://sitebar.org/features.php) and the firefox-plugin.

One of the reasons is that I can install a [sitebar server](http://sitebar.org/downloads.php) in a web-server/web-hotel that I control.

I kind of like to keep my bookmarks under my own control...

Answer (score 0):

There is also this online service called TwoHub located at (surprisingly) www.twohub.com

It will take care of your bookmarks. I use it about a month and am very satisfied with it so far

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [www.pinboard.in](http://www.pinboard.in). I use it on a regular basis and highly recommend it.