# Any good alternatives to delicious?

Tags: bookmarks, delicious

With delicious potentially [shutting down](http://techcrunch.com/2010/12/16/is-yahoo-shutting-down-del-icio-us) what am i to do with all my saved bookmarks? I know i can export them, but what service can i import them into?

Ideally i would like something that:

- Has a chrome extension or bookmarklet
- Imports the tags from delicious along with the bookmarks
- Has a nice web interface that allows me to browse by tag
- Is free (I know this might be pushing it, and i may be swayed otherwise)

Anything like this out there?

Comment: Take a look at this http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/8641/where-can-i-store-my-private-bookmarks-online Obviously ignoring the first answer.

Comment: Doh! You posted your question as [I was typing up my own](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10410/alternatives-to-del-icio-us). :)

Comment: I hope someone will shed light on whether there are good services that fully support **importing** delicious bookmarks, *including the metadata*. Without the carefully chosen tags, my bookmark collection would be a lot less valuable...

Comment: if you would accept to create a new twitter account or flood your existing with new tweets from the delicious import I can write something for you which adds the tags as hashtag to the tweet. see my answer for 'how to use twitter as bookmarking service'

Comment: autonomo.us has a list of [delicious replacements](http://autonomo.us/wiki/Delicious_replacements) on their wiki.

Comment: Delicious may not be on the way out: http://blog.delicious.com/blog/2010/12/whats-next-for-delicious.html

Comment: You can try [Licorize](http://licorize.com/)

Comment: You can try [Google Bookmarks](https://www.google.com/bookmarks).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was a Delicious user since before Yahoo.  Because they stopped innovating, I moved to [Diigo](http://www.diigo.com/).

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/38733/delicious-is-shutting-down.-heres-how-to-migrate-to-diigo-instead/

Comment: Been using it for a bit now, it seems to be what i was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: I really like [Diigo](http://diigo.com). Well-designed. Good set of features.

Answer (score 9):

I have been a happy user of http://pinboard.in for a while now. Pinboard will easily import your delicious bookmarks. Pinboard has always been very fast and I use delibarapp to add/search bookmarks. I highly recommend the service as a happy user.

Comment: Interesting: "The fee is based on the formula (number of users * $0.001), so the earlier you join, the less you pay." Does Pinboard import delicious tags (and notes) too?

Comment: yes.  It imports everything from delicious (although with the mass exodus, it may take a while).  The only downside I've found to Pinboard right now is that it doesn't have the (as) simple URL tag structure that delicious has

Comment: To get your bookmarks out of del.icio.us, go to Settings -> Export/Backup Bookmarks and hit the 'Export' button.

You can then upload the resulting file to Pinboard on the settings page.

Comment: Well, I decided to give it a try, concluding that a $7.23 one-time fee isn't *that* much if it's as good as people are saying. Let's see.

Comment: Looks like a nice minimalistic service. It is interesting to see how the user base is growing today. The sign up price is now $7.91 and growing

Comment: I got in yesterday when the cost was just over $7. The service was slow to import my bookmarks, no doubt due to the mass influx. Give it some time and it will stabilize.

Comment: Does the import preserve delicious tags?

Comment: @neilfein: Yes, it does. I imported 4 years worth of delicious bookmarks with no problems, aside from a long wait (which was due to heavy load).

Answer (score 1):

Also take a look into this nice list https://docs.google.com/document/d/1MYxd_PAR1KXj39Xc2lSfKNZXFq5R2q_5g_9W2Egyibo/preview?authkey=CO2NqaAL&sle=true#

Answer (score 1):

You can consider [exporting your delicious bookmarks to Google Bookmarks](http://google.about.com/b/2006/10/20/move-your-delicious-to-google-bookmarks.htm) as it meets most of your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using twitter for bookmarking. Tweets are easily shareable, yes. But how to search my own tweets including full resolved links with title?

That was one reason to develop the (open source) twitter search at http://jetwick.com

With that you can even see trending links (on the right) for one special search term. Try it: http://jetwick.com?q=delicious

UPDATE:
But with existing urls it is a bit difficult because you would have to flood you twitter account with new url tweets from delicious. Hmmh

Answer (score 0):

You might not be a fan of Yahoo at the moment, but I found Yahoo Bookmarks pretty useful in the past. It has a [JavaScript bookmarklet](http://bookmarks.yahoo.com/tools/showsave) you can drag on to Chrome's toolbar to set bookmarks (I think I used the Safari one - webkit-based).

One other feature is that is integrates into Yahoo Toolbar (Firefox etc.) and arranges your bookmarks like a 'native' bookmark tree, which is accessible via any browser (as it the Bookmarks homepage, of course).

This Delicious decision will be a real downer, as I only just joined myself (some 3-4 months back)....

Answer (score 0):

[pinterest](http://pinterest.com/) are doing well with their boards feature what delicious are trying to do with stacks.

Comment: why is Pinterest a good solution for the question asked? can you expand on your answer?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: this question was closed in February.

Comment: Agreed, but it came up under late posts reviewing. instead of recommending deletion I made a comment instead.

Comment: Seems pretty arbitrary when you consider the content in the accepted answer.