# If Delicious Goes Bye-Bye, what alternative web bookmark tool should I turn to?

Tags: bookmarks, delicious, google-bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any good alternatives to delicious?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10409/any-good-alternatives-to-delicious)

TechCrunch [just posted an article](http://techcrunch.com/2010/12/16/is-yahoo-shutting-down-del-icio-us/) that Yahoo may be shutting down Delicious. I see [Pinboard and google bookmarks](http://pinboard.in/) are some options, but which to go with? Or is there others out there that my google-search-fu is not finding?

I really don't feel like paying for this service and, at a quick glance, google doesn't look to be nearly as good as delicious.

Comment: It looks like pinboards price is going up as we speak. When I first posted this question, it's price was 6.90 and now it is 7.00...interesting.

Comment: the formula is (number of users * 0.001$). genius idea if you ask me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not a web app but, Firefox Sync or Google Sync can do the job if you are using only one of them in your machines.

But, on web apps option, i heard that xmarks is acquired by LastPass and offers free service too. www.xmarks.com , i provides plugins, extensions for major browser too.