# Are there web services similar to del.icio.us?

Tags: delicious

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any good alternatives to delicious?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10409/any-good-alternatives-to-delicious)

I'd like to save and manage my favourite web links. I know del.icio.us, but would like to test other free similar services (better if it's created by Google).

Only web links (no notes, no docs, no images).

Thank you very much.